# Connects to wifi, but not the internet

Tags: wireless, internet, lenovo, connection

I know that there are a lot of similar questions here, and I've read them and tried a lot of them, and nothing works (I'm afraid I might have fudged something up, but I really have no idea). Basically, my computer connects to the wifi (which is fine, I'm on my Chromebook now to post this on the very same wifi), but it won't access the internet.

I'm on a new Lenovo G50-30 (with rtl8723be chip), and running Ubuntu GNOME (I think 14.01, but I'm not sure. A friend installed it for me. As you might suspect, I'm not good with these things). I'm starting to get desperate here, I don't have a lot of money, and don't want to have wasted it on a computer I can't access the internet on.

Apperently, my Chromebook refuses to read the text file (even after uploading it to Drive) in which I put the ifconfig output, but I'll work on it so that I can post it here.

I'd appreciate any help at all!

Answer (score 1):

Open the program called 'Terminal' and type the commands in the grey boxes in the following order:

**Diagnose connectivity to router:**

```
ping <your_router_ip>
```

If you get a response, you are connected to the router -- good. Press 'Ctrl-C' to stop the program.

**Diagnose DNS:**

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If you get a response, your DNS servers are not properly set.
We can fix that, if that's the problem.

**Try getting a new IP/DNS servers from your router**

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

That command produces no output if successful. 
It would also be great if you can get us the output of 'ifconfig'.

Comment: +1 you might want to add how to exit the ping loop (Ctrl-C) - or change it to something like `ping -c4 <your_router_ip>`. Adding the `-v` switch to `dhclient` can be helpful as well.